# debug assertion failed error. don't know what to do with pointer

Tags: debugging, scanf, null-pointer

I get this error when I want to run my code.

Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
Debug Assertion Failed!

program:...sual Studio 2013\ ... \project1.exe
File:f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\stdio\fscanf.c
Line: 52

Expression (stream!=NULL)

For information on how to ...... blah

I checked the internet and other people usually got that error because their pointers when to a null place but I don't think my code has an option for my pointer to go anywhere null.If the pointer's the cause what should i do with it?
any help appreciated thanks.

```
#include <glut.h>
#include<stdio.h>


float ex, ey, ez;
unsigned char po;
void RenderScene(){
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

ex = 1.0f;
ey = 1.0f;
ex = 1.0f;
gluLookAt(ex, ey, ez, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

float vertices[531];


FILE *data;
int i;
fopen_s(&data, "teapot.dat", "r");
fscanf_s(data,"%f",vertices);

for (float *ptr = vertices; *ptr != NULL; ptr++)
    *ptr = *(ptr + 1);


glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);

glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON,0 , 530);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glutSwapBuffers();



}

void    SetupRC(void)
{
// setup clear color
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
void    ChangeSize(GLsizei w, GLsizei h)
{
GLfloat  aspectRatio;
// Prevent a divide by zero
if (h == 0)
    h = 1;       
// Set Viewport to window dimensions
glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
// Reset coordinate system
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
// Establish clipping volume (left, right, bottom, top, near, far)
aspectRatio = (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h;

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

if (po=true)
    gluPerspective(90.f, aspectRatio, 10.f, 200.f);
else
    glOrtho(-100.f, 100.f, -100.f, 100.f, -100.f, 100.f);

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should check whether `fopen_s()` succeeded before blindly passing the value of `data` to `fscanf_s()`...

Comment: I did that and nothing changed :/